# how to restrict user from cancel booking after specific time period in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

When I book a car (Button book click)

```
    var time = DateTime.Now;
    Session["currenttime"] = time;
    var totaltime = DateTime.Now.AddHours(24);
    Session["after24"] = totaltime;
```

When I cancel booking from gridview

```
protected void gvuserbooking_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
    var deltime = DateTime.Now;
    Session["deletetime"] = deltime;
    if (Convert.ToDateTime(Session["after24"]) <= Convert.ToDateTime(Session["deletetime"]))
    {
        //code for deleting a row
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Write("<script>(alert('You Can't Cancel Booking After 24 Hours');</script>");
    }
```

It is not working. and not showing any error.It always goes in if condition whether condition is true or false.

Comment: [Is this wrong?](https://rextester.com/PTKL60234)

Comment: It should throw message if I cancel booking after 24 hours. But It is not going in else condition even after 24 hours of booking. It is going in if condition

Comment: I recommend that you set a breakpoint and inspect each value to find out why the condition isn't being satisfied. Without a [mcve] we can't help you.

Comment: Based on the logic you have mentioned, I think you should use `>=` instead of `<=` in the `if` statement.

Comment: I tried that first, but if I use that It is not deleting my row